# Converting String RDD to Int RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala..I want to know when processing large datasets with scala in spark is it possible to read as int RDD  instead of String RDD

I tried the below:

```
val intArr = sc
              .textFile("Downloads/data/train.csv")
              .map(line=>line.split(","))
              .map(_.toInt)
```

But I am getting the error:

> error: value toInt is not a member of `Array[String]`

I need to convert to int rdd because down the line i need to do the below

```
val vectors = intArr.map(p => Vectors.dense(p))
```

which requires the type to be integer

Any kind of help is truly appreciated..thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understood, one line should create one vector, so it should goes like:

```
val result = sc
           .textFile("Downloads/data/train.csv")
           .map(line => line.split(","))
           .map(numbers => Vectors.dense(numbers.map(_.toInt)))
```

`numbers.map(_.toInt)` will map every element of array to int, so result type will be `Array[Int]`

Comment: @sivagama please accept this as the correct answer.