# How to convert string element to numeric one in RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I want to convert the string elements in the following RDD

```
    data0 = sc.parallelize( [('0', '2.023'), ('0.2', '4.235'), ('1.23', '0.45'), ('1.23', '10.2'), ('1.0', '20.0')] )
```

to be numeric values. So the expected output is

```
[(0, 2.023), (0.2, 4.235), (1.23, 0.45), (1.23, 10.2), (1.0, 20.0)]
```

I tried

```
data0.map(lambda x: x.split(',')).map(lambda x: (float(x[0]),float(x[1])))
```

and

```
data0.map(lambda line: line.split(",")).map(lambda numbers: Vectors.dense(numbers.map(_.toInt)))
```

in [Converting String RDD to Int RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727964/converting-string-rdd-to-int-rdd).
However, neither of them worked.

I know perhaps there are some approaches converting RDD to dataframe first and then doing it. What if I want to finish my task in RDD without changing it to dataframe (because maybe very time costly), how shall I do? 
This is just an example. In a more general case, suppose that there are many elements in one row, which doesn't enable you to formulating one by one. Then how can we do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to split a tuple by comma. Strings can be split by comma. `"0.01, 0.02".split(",")` will return `["0.01", "0.02"]`. But you already have a tuple `("0.01", "0.02")`, and you just need to convert both the elements to float. You're writing the correct code, just making an extra unnecessary first step due to which the code is failing.

Works for me:

```
data0 = sc.parallelize([('0', '2.023'), ('0.2', '4.235'), ('1.23', '0.45'), ('1.23', '10.2'), ('1.0', '20.0')])
data0.take(5)
# [('0', '2.023'), ('0.2', '4.235'), ('1.23', '0.45'), ('1.23', '10.2'), ('1.0', '20.0')]
# Convert to float
data0.map(lambda x: (float(x[0]), float(x[1]))).take(5)
# [(0.0, 2.023), (0.2, 4.235), (1.23, 0.45), (1.23, 10.2), (1.0, 20.0)]
```

#### EDIT:

If you want to generalize to all elements of a `tuple` element:

```
data0.map(lambda x: tuple([float(i) for i in x]))
```

Comment: Thank you. Here, we only have two elements each row. What if I have many elements in which it's not easy format one by one, how shall we do?

Comment: @Samson I have generalized my answer to convert all elements in the `tuple`

Comment: what should i do if i have a null value? like ('2.33', '')

Comment: @user3325706 You can add an if else condition on x (to check null or not) inside the list comprehension